# SalesForce Analytics API filter problems

Tags: salesforce, analytics

I am trying to use the Salesforce Analytics api to get a report filtered by date, but when I apply the date filters it does not seem to stick, only the default filter applies.

Here is the POST data that I am sending

```
{
    "reportMetadata": {
        "aggregates": [
            "FORMULA1",
            "FORMULA2",
            "FORMULA3",
            "RowCount"
        ],
        "currency": null,
        "detailColumns": [
            "SUBJECT",
            "DUE_DATE",
            "PRIORITY",
            "STATUS",
            "TASK",
            "ACCOUNT",
            "CONTACT",
            "LEAD",
            "OPPORTUNITY"
        ],
        "developerName": "me",
        "groupingsAcross": [
            {
                "dateGranularity": "None",
                "name": "CALLDISPOSITION",
                "sortAggregate": null,
                "sortOrder": "Asc"
            }
        ],
        "groupingsDown": [
            {
                "dateGranularity": "None",
                "name": "ASSIGNED",
                "sortAggregate": null,
                "sortOrder": "Asc"
            }
        ],
        "historicalSnapshotDates": [],
        "id": "00OC0000006nlWpMAI",
        "name": "report",
        "reportBooleanFilter": "1 AND 2 AND 3",
        "reportFilters": [
            {
                "column": "CALLTYPE",
                "operator": "equals",
                "value": "Outbound"
            },
            {
                "value": "2014-08-01",
                "column": "Activity.qbdialer__Call_Date_Time__c",
                "operator": "greaterOrEqual"
            },
            {
                "value": "2014-08-31",
                "column": "Activity.qbdialer__Call_Date_Time__c",
                "operator": "lessOrEqual"
            }
        ],
        "reportFormat": "MATRIX",
        "reportType": {
            "label": "Tasks and Events",
            "type": "Activity"
        }
    }
}
```

and here is what I get back

```
Array
(
    [status] => Array
        (
            [http_code] => 200
        )

    [contents] => Array
        (
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [completionDate] => 2014-08-19T17:23:26Z
                    [id] => 0LGC00000024PlIOAU
                    [ownerId] => 005C0000003KHKbIAO
                    [reportId] => 00OC0000006nlWpMAI
                    [reportName] => report
                    [requestDate] => 2014-08-19T17:23:25Z
                    [status] => Success
                    [type] => ReportInstance
                )

            [allData] => 1
            [factMap] => Array
                (
                    [T!2] => Array
                        (
                            [aggregates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] =>
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 6.67%
                                            [value] => 6.66666667
                                        )

                                    [2] =>
                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 1
                                            [value] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [T!T] => Array
                        (
                            [aggregates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] =>
                                    [1] =>
                                    [2] =>
                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 15
                                            [value] => 15
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [T!1] => Array
                        (
                            [aggregates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] =>
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 13.33%
                                            [value] => 13.33333333
                                        )

                                    [2] =>
                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 2
                                            [value] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [0!0] => Array
                        (
                            [aggregates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 3.00
                                            [value] => 3
                                        )

                                    [1] =>
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 0.25
                                            [value] => 0.25
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 12
                                            [value] => 12
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [0!T] => Array
                        (
                            [aggregates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] =>
                                    [1] =>
                                    [2] =>
                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 15
                                            [value] => 15
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [T!0] => Array
                        (
                            [aggregates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] =>
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 80.00%
                                            [value] => 80
                                        )

                                    [2] =>
                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 12
                                            [value] => 12
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [0!2] => Array
                        (
                            [aggregates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 0.00
                                            [value] => 0
                                        )

                                    [1] =>
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 0.00
                                            [value] => 0
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 1
                                            [value] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [0!1] => Array
                        (
                            [aggregates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 1.00
                                            [value] => 1
                                        )

                                    [1] =>
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 0.50
                                            [value] => 0.5
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [label] => 2
                                            [value] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [groupingsAcross] => Array
                (
                    [groupings] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [groupings] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [key] => 0
                                    [label] => -
                                    [value] =>
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [groupings] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [key] => 1
                                    [label] => Contact
                                    [value] => Contact
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [groupings] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [key] => 2
                                    [label] => Correct Contact
                                    [value] => Correct Contact
                                )

                        )

                )

            [groupingsDown] => Array
                (
                    [groupings] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [groupings] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [key] => 0
                                    [label] => first sftest1
                                    [value] => 005C0000003KHKbIAO
                                )

                        )

                )

            [hasDetailRows] =>
            [reportExtendedMetadata] => Array
                (
                    [aggregateColumnInfo] => Array
                        (
                            [RowCount] => Array
                                (
                                    [acrossGroupingContext] =>
                                    [dataType] => int
                                    [downGroupingContext] =>
                                    [label] => Record Count
                                )

                            [FORMULA1] => Array
                                (
                                    [acrossGroupingContext] => CALLDISPOSITION
                                    [dataType] => double
                                    [downGroupingContext] => ASSIGNED
                                    [label] => Ring Time
                                )

                            [FORMULA3] => Array
                                (
                                    [acrossGroupingContext] => CALLDISPOSITION
                                    [dataType] => double
                                    [downGroupingContext] => ASSIGNED
                                    [label] => Average Ring Time
                                )

                            [FORMULA2] => Array
                                (
                                    [acrossGroupingContext] => CALLDISPOSITION
                                    [dataType] => percent
                                    [downGroupingContext] => GRAND_SUMMARY
                                    [label] => Group Average
                                )

                        )

                    [detailColumnInfo] => Array
                        (
                            [SUBJECT] => Array
                                (
                                    [dataType] => string
                                    [label] => Subject
                                )

                            [DUE_DATE] => Array
                                (
                                    [dataType] => date
                                    [label] => Date
                                )

                            [PRIORITY] => Array
                                (
                                    [dataType] => picklist
                                    [label] => Priority
                                )

                            [STATUS] => Array
                                (
                                    [dataType] => picklist
                                    [label] => Status
                                )

                            [TASK] => Array
                                (
                                    [dataType] => boolean
                                    [label] => Task
                                )

                            [ACCOUNT] => Array
                                (
                                    [dataType] => string
                                    [label] => Company / Account
                                )

                            [CONTACT] => Array
                                (
                                    [dataType] => string
                                    [label] => Contact
                                )

                            [LEAD] => Array
                                (
                                    [dataType] => string
                                    [label] => Lead
                                )

                            [OPPORTUNITY] => Array
                                (
                                    [dataType] => string
                                    [label] => Opportunity
                                )

                        )

                    [groupingColumnInfo] => Array
                        (
                            [ASSIGNED] => Array
                                (
                                    [dataType] => string
                                    [groupingLevel] => 0
                                    [label] => Assigned
                                )

                            [CALLDISPOSITION] => Array
                                (
                                    [dataType] => string
                                    [groupingLevel] => 0
                                    [label] => Call Result
                                )

                        )

                )

            [reportMetadata] => Array
                (
                    [aggregates] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => FORMULA1
                            [1] => FORMULA2
                            [2] => FORMULA3
                            [3] => RowCount
                        )

                    [currency] =>
                    [detailColumns] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SUBJECT
                            [1] => DUE_DATE
                            [2] => PRIORITY
                            [3] => STATUS
                            [4] => TASK
                            [5] => ACCOUNT
                            [6] => CONTACT
                            [7] => LEAD
                            [8] => OPPORTUNITY
                        )

                    [developerName] => Ring_Time_By_Agent
                    [groupingsAcross] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [dateGranularity] => None
                                    [name] => CALLDISPOSITION
                                    [sortAggregate] =>
                                    [sortOrder] => Asc
                                )

                        )

                    [groupingsDown] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [dateGranularity] => None
                                    [name] => ASSIGNED
                                    [sortAggregate] =>
                                    [sortOrder] => Asc
                                )

                        )

                    [historicalSnapshotDates] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [id] => 00OC0000006nlWpMAI
                    [name] => report
                    [reportBooleanFilter] =>
                    [reportFilters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [column] => CALLTYPE
                                    [operator] => equals
                                    [value] => Outbound
                                )

                        )

                    [reportFormat] => MATRIX
                    [reportType] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Tasks and Events
                            [type] => Activity
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

As you can see in the results only the CALLTYPE column filter applied (this is the default filter).

Does anyone see anything wrong with the POST data that I am sending?

I have tried using other reports and other date columns to filter on, but it is always the same, only the default filters apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I was not setting the header Content-type to application/json. Once I did that the filters started working.